# dynamic toggle effect in jquery and in cs cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, toggle

hi i am using cs cart and i want to make toggle effect on categories dynamically in a tpl file, suppose i have more than 100 categories than how i can make the change in javascript that if i click on one main category than it will show the subcategories of only that main category and if i click on another main category than it will show subcategories of that main category, it become difficult if i have more than 100 main category because i cannot write code for all categories differently and categories are coming from database. Here is the code:
i can not write same function for different categories value like 167,175,174 and son.
please help me.
thanks in advance

```
{** block-description:text_links **}
{literal}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".167h").click(function(){  
    $(".167c").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(".175h").click(function(){  
    $(".175c").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(".174h").click(function(){  
    $(".174c").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

</script>
{/literal}

{if $items}
<ul class="text-links">
    {foreach from=$items item="category"}
    {**$category|print_r**}
    {if $category.level eq 1 }
    <div class="{$category.category_id}h"><li class="level-{$category.level|default:0}{if $category.active || $category|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} cm-active{/if}"><a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}">{$category.category}</a></li></div>
    {else}
    <div class="{$category.parent_id}c" style="display: none;"><li><a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}">{$category.category}</a></li></div>
    {/if}
    {/foreach}
</ul>
{/if}

   enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This Code

i have Coded some for you. please try this out

```
    {** block-description:text_links **}
{literal}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cat_cat_h").click(function(){  
$(this).closest("cat_par_c").slideToggle("slow");
});

});

</script>
{/literal}

{if $items}
<ul class="text-links">
{foreach from=$items item="category"}
{**$category|print_r**}
{if $category.level eq 1 }
<div class="{$category.category_id}h cat_cat_h"><li class="level-{$category.level|default:0}{if $category.active || $category|fn_check_is_active_menu_item:$block.type} cm-active{/if}"><a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}">   {$category.category}</a></li></div>
{else}
<div class="{$category.parent_id}c cat_par_c" style="display: none;"><li><a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}">{$category.category}</a></li></div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
{/if}
```